# Bash, how to check if a C program times out

Tags: c, bash

I want to run a C program foo.c thats compiled to foo within a bash script and see check if it times out.

There is one parameter to foo and the 10 second timeout.
I want to check if the program foo times out or executes. If it times out I want to exit 0.

```
#!/bin/sh
# -*-sh-*-
/foo $1 10
if [$? -eq 0]
    then
        exit 0;
fi
exit 1;
```

Comment: Either one should suffice, the issue is that the syntax is breaking things. Line 5 is command not found.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `timeout` command:

```
timeout 10s ./foo
if [ $? -eq 124 ] ; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

From [`man timeout`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout):

> If the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit with status 124.  Otherwise, exit with the status of COMMAND.   If
>          no  signal is specified, send the TERM signal upon timeout.  The TERM signal kills any process that does not block or catch that signal.
>          It may be necessary to use the KILL (9) signal, since this signal cannot be caught, in which case the exit status is 128+9  rather  than
>          124.

Comment: If I try that as a bash script I get command not found for timeout for timeout 10s /foo $1

Comment: isn't it better to use `-eq` in `if` statement?

Comment: @ab3rc If you are not working on GNU/Linux, you'll have to install the timeout command. Installing GNU coreutils will do it.